# how can I use a variable to set tween duration?

Tags: variables, createjs, tween, tweenjs

```
var root = this;
function go(){
    createjs.Tween
        .get(root.mvpano, {override:true} )
        .to({x:100}, duration: **here I want  to place a variable**, createjs.Ease.cubicOut);
};
```

---

So that... is posible to use a variable to set the tween duration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put a variable in as any property (see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thhr60v5/)). Note that once you create the tween, if the variable changes, the tween will not.

```
function go(duration, position){
    createjs.Tween
        .get(s, {override:true} )
        .to({x:position}, duration, createjs.Ease.cubicOut);
};
```